# Attempting to find an element returns "Proxy?"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, proxy

I've been using selenium in java to attempt to .sendKeys to an element, however when I attempt to .sendKeys to this element it always crashed and gave me the error

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

So, I attempted to check the element using javascript, and make sure its valid, and I got "Proxy" returned. What is this?

I typed

```
document.getElementById('order_billing_name')
```

and instead of being returned with the element by the id I specified, I got

```
Proxy {stepUp: ƒ, stepDown: ƒ, checkValidity: ƒ, reportValidity: ƒ, 
setCustomValidity: ƒ, …}
[[Handler]]:
Object
[[Target]]:
input#order_billing_name.string.required
[[IsRevoked]]:
false
```

instead of what I was expecting, which was

```
<input first_and_last="true" placeholder="name" class="string required" type="text" name="order[billing_name]" id="order_billing_name">
```

I've tried locating it using cssSelector, xpath, name, nothing works and returns this weird proxy object. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problems.  Supreme is doing it to be tricky.  I think they are using the proxy object to run functions against the form for bot detection.  What's weird is that I can access the element and write to the input using jQuery but inside of selenium it throws an error about not being a node.

Comment: hah, someone found this post. i ended up actually solving the issue; you can either use a different driver (firefox driver, microsoft egde driver, opera driver) or you can change the id of the element you want and sendKeys() to the element through the new id. for example, you change the id of "order_billing_name" to "newID" through javascript, and then you use driver.findElement(By.id("newID")).sendKeys("test") and it will work. i was under the impression that this might cause declines but it worked and was able to get 2 blue camo pants when they dropped last season